# Oracle Sql Developer (Version 20.2). Schedule a report

Tags: sql, oracle, scheduled-tasks, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that takes hours to run and extract. I am looking to get that query run by Oracle Developer automatically (e.g. overnight), extracted and saved in a designated folder.

I was not able to find any clear instructions online - I am quite new to this and was wondering if anyone could share a link or some instructions on how to achieve that, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what i would do is use SQLcl instead of SQL Developer - smaller, better for command line, which makes it easier to schedule - then look at the SPOOL command. there are lots of questions/answers here on how to build a script to connect, run a query, spool to file

Comment: even better though - tune your query

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thank you. I am fairly new to SQL and my query tracks supplier spend through multiple tables (GL, PO, AP, Supplier) and generates almost 1,5M lines. I honestly did everything I could to optimise it. I am nor familiar with SQLcl and was hoping that there was a simple way to schedule a report in the SQL Developer.

Comment: if you insist on your path, https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/07/sql-developer-4-0-and-the-command-line-interface-cli/ - but we're going to be deprecating this feature in the future - and it will be SLOW, better to take the few minutes to learn SPOOL. Also 1.5M rows isn't a lot of data as far as a database is concerned - don't give up on tuning opportunities for your slow sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can schedule a job using sql developer(assuming you have admin right)

[image]

Comment: your job would need to account for the output of the query, and to be able to place it somewhere the client can access it, but yes. Or create a Materialized View.

Comment: @scott yu Thank you. I did try that. How do I assign my script to the job I am creating? Just copy and paste it into the PL/SQL Block window? When I do it I get some errors: Failed to process SQL command
- ORA-16612: string value too long for attribute "job_action"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 135
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 271
ORA-06512: at line 2                                                                                                 
How do I define where my report should be saved? Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: for pl/sql block you need to put in begin and end; block

Comment: the following is my pl/sql block example, BEGIN 
insert into testuser.emp values (to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI'),'it'); 
commit ; 
END; /* you can insert you report to a temp table */

Comment: use the following instruction for running sql script------------https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/scheduler-enhancements-12cr1#sql-script

Comment: Thank you All for your help.